# Does WordPress change my whole web design after installing it?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am thinking of which tool to make a blog page for my website I should use. I found WordPress the most commonly used tool. However, I am confused at the use of the software. I just want to use it for only a blog page on my website. I do not want WordPress to effect on the rest of my website pages because I created my website without any frameworks.

Can anyone tell me whether WordPress effects on my whole web design layout or not and how it effects on my website.

Thank you,

Joey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install WordPress in a separate folder on your website. This will not affect other files.

You will be asked during installation in which folder you want it to be installed.

As example, you can install WordPress in a folder named `/blog`. Accordingly, you can visit example.com/blog to enter the WordPress section of your website.

Also, always have a backup of your files.

Comment: ＠Faith Thank you for telling me. You gave me a crystal clear. I understood it. Thank you so much! Which would you choose if you were thinking of using WordPress or Medium for your blog?